# MySQL Database Error: Constant, random or timezone-dependent expressions in (sub)partitioning function are not allowed

Tags: mysql

I was tried to make partition by the `timestamp` in `mysql` table. But it is returning an error

```
CREATE TABLE tblemployeepunch (
  fld_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  fld_date Varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  fld_rawpunchdate varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  fld_rawpunchtime varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  fld_cardno varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  fld_reasoncard varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  fld_mode varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  fld_punchdatetime varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  fld_crtdate  TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  UNIQUE KEY fld_id (fld_id,fld_crtdate),
  KEY in_timesheet (fld_cardno,fld_punchdatetime,fld_mode,fld_rawpunchtime),
  KEY in_emppunch (fld_cardno,fld_rawpunchdate,fld_punchdatetime)
  )
  PARTITION BY HASH(DAYOFYEAR(fld_crtdate))
PARTITIONS 12;
```

Comment: So? What's unclear about the error message?

Comment: How resolve this error and make partition with timestamp datatype ?

Answer (score 4):

Well, the error message is quite clear. Don't partition by values which are in a timezone-dependent column. Use a column which has datatype `date`, `datetime` or `int` (by calculating `DAYOFYEAR(fld_crtdate)` beforehand in a separate column) or any other.

Comment: thanks, i know this , but how can i do partititon with timestamp dataype column

Comment: Well, you can make the fld_crtdate column datetime instead of timestamp, but then you can't have the default value.