# Why MySQL table partitioning on a datetime column gives error of timezone dependent?

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I've come across a couple of questions like my question:

- [MySQL table partitioning on timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21099265/mysql-table-partitioning-on-timestamp)
- [MySQL Database Error: Constant, random or timezone-dependent expressions in (sub)partitioning function are not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18630927/mysql-database-error-constant-random-or-timezone-dependent-expressions-in-sub)

And some other. They all explained the same problem but they weren't my issue.

**My problem is that** my column is `datetime NOT NULL` and I have made it a primary key by table id:

```
PRIMARY KEY (id, start_time)
```

Now I used the below command to partition my table:

```
alter table MY_TABLE partition by range (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start_time)) ( 
partition p2012 values less than (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2012-01-01 00:00:00')),
partition p2013 values less than (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-01-01 00:00:00')), 
partition p2014 values less than (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-01-01 00:00:00')), 
partition p2015 values less than (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-01-01 00:00:00')), 
partition p2016 values less than (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2016-01-01 00:00:00')),
partition p2017 values less than (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2017-01-01 00:00:00')), 
partition pfuture values less than (MAXVALUE));
```

Everything seems right, and When I `describe MY_TABLE` it gives information of:

```
start_time        | datetime         | NO   | PRI | 0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

When run the command above for partitioning I get the error of:

```
ERROR 1486 (HY000): Constant, random or timezone-dependent expressions in (sub)partitioning function are not allowed
```

`datetime` is not timezone dependent like `timestamp`, and it is not `constant`. What could be the reason for such an error?

Comment: Datetime is indeed not time zone dependent, by unix_timestamp() is... Yes, I know that it returns value in UTC, nevertheless, it is a timestamp.

Comment: @Shadow `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` is the sample code of MySQL documentation itself for partitioning, so it should not raise error.

Comment: I see only the year() function in the partitioning documentation, not the unix_timestamp. Have you tried with the year() instead?

Comment: Ok, found the example with unix timestamp, but there the column type is also timestamp.

Comment: Partitioning is rarely useful.  Please explain why you want to use it; I may be able to convince you that an index will do just as good.

Comment: @RickJames My table has hover 40M rows spanned over different years, from 2012 to 2017 (and it will be more). When I want to query based on a metric I use start_time to limit the query scope and then I use my specific metric. Let's say I want to group by status. I already have an index on start_time and have index on (start_time,status).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [22.2.1 RANGE Partitioning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-range.html)
>
> ...
>
> Partition the table by RANGE COLUMNS, using a DATE or DATETIME column
>   as the partitioning column.
>
> ...

Try:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `MY_TABLE`
PARTITION BY RANGE COLUMNS (`start_time`)
(
  PARTITION `p2012` VALUES LESS THAN ('2012-01-01 00:00:00'),
  PARTITION `p2013` VALUES LESS THAN ('2013-01-01 00:00:00'), 
  PARTITION `p2014` VALUES LESS THAN ('2014-01-01 00:00:00'), 
  PARTITION `p2015` VALUES LESS THAN ('2015-01-01 00:00:00'), 
  PARTITION `p2016` VALUES LESS THAN ('2016-01-01 00:00:00'),
  PARTITION `p2017` VALUES LESS THAN ('2017-01-01 00:00:00'), 
  PARTITION `pfuture` VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)
);
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dwL3Ms2Y6dg3kWkLyWtnGt/0).